# How to send email from desktop applciation using the Mail app in windows 8 or 10?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, email, mfc

I developed a desktop application and I send emails using the default email client application installed on windows by the "mailto" protocol.

In the past windows used to come with "Windows Live Mail" and this used to work fine.

Form windows 8, they replaced the desktop application "Windows Live mail" by the "Mail" app. But My desktop application does not recognized it. When there is no email client installed.

So, how can a desktop application developed in C++ MFC or C# .net send emails using the pre-installed "Mail" app in windows 8 or 10?

Comment: Can't say I've tried that. In C and C++ I use cURL. If I'm not mistaken C# can use System.Net.Mail to do the work for you.

Comment: I don't know of a *"'mailto' command"*. Are you referring to the [mailto Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737.aspx) instead?

Comment: Yes, I meant mailto protocol, I fixed the question.